# how output display in jsp using jstl, servlet

Tags: java, jsp, maven, servlets, jstl

Sorry form my english. I began to study the technology and javaEE not clear to me some points. I using maven and pattern DAO. In data base i add image, but i dont know how its image output from jsp using jstl and servlet. Please tell me how to get the pictures in jsp

object class **Post**:

```
public class Posts {

//code

    @Lob
    @Column(name="IMAGE", nullable=false)
    private byte[] image;
}

//code

public void setImage(byte[] image) { this.image = image; }
public byte[] getImge() { return image; }
}
```

**PostDao** interface:

```
public interface PostDao {
//code
public Collection getAllPost();
}
```

**PostDaoImpl**

```
public class PostDaoImpl implements PostDao{
//code
    public Collection getAllPost() { //this method return list object
        Session session = null;
        List posts = new ArrayList<Posts>();
        try{
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            posts = session.createCriteria(Posts.class).list();

        } catch(Exception e) { outputError("getAllPost", e); 
        } finally { closeSession(session); }
        return posts;
    }
//code
}
```

in servlet **indexuser**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        //get session
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        try{
            //get collection allpost object
            Collection allpost = Factory.getInstance().getPostDAO().getAllPost();

            request.setAttribute("allpost", allpost);

            request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response); 
        } catch(Exception e) { 
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally{
            if(session!=null && session.isOpen())
                session.close();
        }
    }
```

And **index.jsp** using JSTL

```
<c:forEach var="allpost" items="${allpost}">
        <img src="${allpost.image}" alt="...">
</c:forEach>
```

Error:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'image' not readable on
>   type app.web.landingpage.object.Posts     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperty.read(BeanELResolver.java:297)    at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperty.access$000(BeanELResolver.java:245)
>     at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:85)
>   .............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your `Posts#getImge` it should be `Posts#getImage`. When you access a property of a class using EL it will invoke get method of that property.

So change your `Post` as follows

```
public class Posts {
    @Lob
    @Column(name="IMAGE", nullable=false)
    private byte[] image;

    //code

    public void setImage(byte[] image) { this.image = image; }
    public byte[] getImage() { return image; }
}
```